# Javascript OnClick needs double instead of single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

Here is a short script to find results out of the array (ar_menu_ref). The results are links with a simple url. But I need to double click to open the link.

Input > liveSearchValue (user enters a value)
div > liveSearchResultList (results generated by liveSearchMenu())

The first click on the generated -link runs "liveSearchMenu()" again. But why? There is no "onclick", registred event or anything else on this html tag (tested and debuged with IE11).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script>
      var ar_menu_ref = new Array( new Array("home", "http://google.de"), new Array("home zwei", "http://google.de"), new Array("home drei", "http://google.de"), new Array("home vier", "http://google.de"), new Array("home fuenf", "http://google.de"), new Array("home sechs", "http://google.de"), new Array("home sieben", "http://google.de"), new Array("home acht", "http://google.de"), new Array("home neun", "http://google.de"), new Array("home zehn", "http://google.de"), new Array("home elf", "http://google.de"), new Array("home zwoelf", "http://google.de"));
      var ar_findings = new Array();
      var string;
      var index;
      function liveSearchMenu(){
        string = $("#liveSearchValue").val();
        ar_findings = new Array();
        for(var i=0; i<ar_menu_ref.length && ar_findings.length < 10 ; i++){ 
          index = ar_menu_ref[i][0].indexOf(string);
          if(index >= 0){
            ar_findings.push(i);
          }
        }

        $("#liveSearchResultList").html("");
        for(var j=0; j<ar_findings.length; j++){ 
          $("#liveSearchResultList").append("<a href='"+ ar_menu_ref[ar_findings[j]][1] +"'>" + ar_menu_ref[ar_findings[j]][0] + "</a><br/>");
        }
        console.debug(string);
        return true;
      }

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input').bind('change keyup',function (){
          liveSearchMenu();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="liveSearchValue" type="text" value="">
    <div id="liveSearchResultList">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first click on the generated -link runs "liveSearchMenu()" again. But why?

```
$('input').bind('change keyup',function (){
  liveSearchMenu();
});
```

This is the code that listens to your `input`. It listens for change in any input box, but it also listens for any release of keys(keyup) in any input boxes.

Perhaps you misunderstand what `change` does. It does NOT fire when the element's value changes, instead, it fires only when 2 conditions are met:

- The element blurs (loses focus);
- The element has a different value than when it gained focus.

Edit: Thanks to [Crisim Il Numenoreano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757095/crisim-il-numenoreano) for helping me be more elaborate in my explanation. :)

Comment: you should update your answer, the problem is that it monitor for keyup, then when it blur from the input control it fire the 'change' event

Comment: But the generated link "<a>" is no input-field. So it should open the link and should not run my function.

Comment: when you blur from the input (while you are clicking on the link) the link will be regenerate. so the element you clicked on will no more be accessible

Comment: @Patrick: Updated my answer now. Perhaps you misunderstood what `change` actually does?

Comment: turbopipp: Yes, you're right. I misunderstood what "change" does. I removed "change" and it works fine. Thanks a lot.